# Using two Tables to show SQL data on one Screen

Tags: php

I am still battelling to show data from two different tables on one screen. The tables both contain one common field name, all i want is to filter on that field name and be able to alter and display details from that line or lines based on that field name they share.

The two tables are:

members and recipients

In members it has a primary key member_id and it is unique. Then in recipients I created a member_id field that needs to link to the members table unique member_id as well.

The following code calls information from members table

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("stingin_epanic", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_msisdn='$slusername'");
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Membership</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Registration Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Copy of ID</th>
    </tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['member_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><font color=blue>" . $row['member_msisdn'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['asdate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['aedate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['attid'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This works great and gives me what i need. I am also calling member_id here to show the primary key.

On same page i am trying to call information related to the member from another table using the following code. Note that the information is supposed to be linked to the member_id of the first code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("stingin_epanic", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members a INNER JOIN recipients b ON member_id = member_id WHERE member_msisdn=$slusername");
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    </tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<td><font color=blue>" . $row['recipient_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['recipient_msisdn'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<td><font color=blue>" . $row['recipient_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['recipient_msisdn'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Using the second code i get no results as it is calling no information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use mysqli instead of mysql functions
2. Use aliases in You SQL queries.

change this

```
"SELECT * FROM members a INNER JOIN recipients b ON member_id = member_id WHERE member_msisdn=$slusername"
```

on this

```
"SELECT * FROM members a INNER JOIN recipients b ON a.member_id = b.member_id WHERE member_msisdn=$slusername"
```

Maybe this will help.

Comment: Not a problem :). Check this answer as 'accepted' and vote up :)

Comment: And..... Please make sure you properly escape your values befor using them in a SQL statement, or use 'binding'. This code may be vulnerable to SQL injection!